# How to add a new post first in the list of posts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I want to add a new post using the method `getPictures()` in the component `GalleryComponent` (this is the parent component) which "post.id" is more than 10, the first in the list, and all other posts "post.id" which less than 10 add in turn.
I am trying to do this using the condition in the method `getPictures()` but I get an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' and 'push' of undefined".

**Parent component code GalleryComponent:**

```js
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
    collection: Picture[];

    constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPictures();
    }

    getPictures() {
        this.galleryService.getPictures().subscribe((data: Picture[]) => {
            data.forEach(post => {
                if (post.id > 10) {
                    this.collection.unshift(post);
                } else {
                    this.collection.push(post);
                }
            });
        })
    }
}
```

**Parent component template GalleryComponent link to component GalleryAddComponent:**

```html
<a routerLink="/gallery-add" class="btn btn-outline-success tog">
                    Add New Post
                </a>
```

**Child component code GalleryAddComponent:**

```js
  export class GalleryAddComponent implements OnInit {
    isAdded: boolean = false;

    constructor( private galleryService: GalleryService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    
    addPost(title: string, url: string): void {
        this.galleryService.add(title, url).subscribe(res => {
            this.isAdded = true;
        });
    }
}
```

**GalleryService with requests to the server:**

```js
export class GalleryService {
    galleryUrl: string = 'http://localhost:5555/posts';
    httpOptions: object = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    };
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getPictures(): Observable<Picture[]> {
        return  this.http.get<Picture[]>(`${this.galleryUrl}`);
    }

    add(title: string, url: string): Observable<Picture> {
        const  postObj = {
          title,
            url
        };
        return this.http.post<Picture>(this.galleryUrl, postObj, this.httpOptions);
    }
}
```

**Picture modal:**

```js
export interface Picture {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    url: string
}
```

Comment: Could you show your Picture modal

Comment: watch update of code

Comment: Looks like u declared `collection` in your GalleryComponent  but never initialized it. Initialize it on declaration, e.g. `collection: Picture[] = [];` or in the constructor.

Comment: Iam Added my answer please check and let you know if any error,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for suggestion let try this once,

```
collection: Picture[]=[];


getPictures() {
        this.galleryService.getPictures().subscribe((data: Picture[]) => {
            data.forEach(post => {
                if (post.id > 10) {
                    this.collection.splice(0,0,post);  //here is updated one line
                } else {
                    this.collection.push(post);
                }
            });
        })
    }
```

I hope its solve your prblm.